# Add whatis hooks into bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash

I just discovered whatis and want to add information into my bash scripts.

What is the best way off adding information into bash scripts for

```
  whatis
```

to pick up?

Comment: `man whatis` will enlight you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`whatis` gets all the the information from *whatis database*, which is generated using the command `makewhatis`.

There are two ways you can add an entry into the database.

1. Create and install the man page for your program or script, then run `makewhatis`.
2. Edit *whatis database* manually.(Not suggested)

`makewhatis` picks up the first line from the *NAME* section of the man page of your command.

The location of *whatis database* on my machine is `/usr/share/man/whatis`, here's how it looks like..

```
ABORT(7)                 - abort the current transaction
ALTER_AGGREGATE(7)       - change the definition of an aggregate function
ALTER_COLLATION(7)       - change the definition of a collation
ALTER_CONVERSION(7)      - change the definition of a conversion
...
ping(8)                  - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to network hosts
...
```

And here's the output of `man ping`

```
NAME
     ping -- send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to network hosts

SYNOPSIS
     ping [-AaCDdfnoQqRrv] [-b boundif] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking it would be a section in shell script itself.